# extra qualification member GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

I know the common answer for this question, but for some reason I get the error when using the right syntax, on Code::Blocks, I'll post a sample to show I'm not bluffing:

```
  class BulletPlacer : sf::Drawable
  {
     public:
        BulletPlacer();
        BulletPlacer(const unsigned Quantity);

        ~BulletPlacer();
  };
```

That was a small portion of the hpp file.

```
   BulletPlacer::BulletPlacer()
     :Amount(0), Min(0)
   {}

   BulletPlacer::BulletPlacer(const unsigned Quantity)
     :Amount(Quantity), Min(0)
   {
       Bullet shot;
       ShotVec.reserve(Amount);
       for(unsigned i = 0; i < Amount; ++i)
       { ShotVec.push_back(shot); }
   }

   BulletPlacer::~BulletPlacer() { PolVecV.clear(); ShotVec.clear(); }
```

And that was the cpp. It compiled fine until I began refactoring the class and I get the error with all the methods. I also get other errors that have no place at all and I get them with all the functions in the class. I even redownloaded a GCC version only to find that it gives me the exact same result.

Here's the simplified version of the error log:

```
error: extra qualification 'BulletPlacer::' on member 'BulletPlacer' [-fpermissive]|
error: 'BulletPlacer::BulletPlacer()' cannot be overloaded|
error: with 'BulletPlacer::BulletPlacer()'|
```

And it gets repeated like this with all functions. It's very annoying since I can't advance at all with my SFML game just because of this and checking a 300 lines file for possible errors just because the compiler is mad at me is no fun at all. And no, none of the files that gets used by "BulletPlacer" gets this.

And it gets worse, a totally unrelated class gets something similar as well:

```
error: cannot define member function 'BulletPlacer::Enemy::Enemy' within 'BulletPlacer'
```

When the class doesn't even include the file...

I'm using GCC 4.7.1

Thanks in advance for any help I may get.

Comment: A class or structure in a header file missing the closing brace and/or semicolon?

Comment: yup, when there are a lot of random looking errors, typically its 1 very trivial punctuation problem.

Comment: What is the very first error that shows up?

Comment: The first error to show up is in the extra qualification on the constructor, the error "cannot define member function 'BulletPlacer::Enemy::Enemy' within 'BulletPlacer'" appears only when I try to compile a file alone and not with the common build icon.

Comment: Also I've checked my code over and over for trivial stuff (it has happened quite often), but so far I haven't found anything that actually fixes the problem. The includes seem fine as well. I'm at wit's end...

Comment: Carlos, try the `clang` compiler (part of LLVM suite). It has much more friendly diagnostics.

Comment: Present a _complete_ (but minimal) testcase. The error isn't in the snippet you decided to show us, rendering this whole enterprise rather pointless.

Comment: That's the problem itself, since I don't know what exactly reproduces the error, and the whole code itself is too big to post here.

Comment: I found what was wrong (?), apparently one of the comments had a backslash in it. Since it was a comment I just ignored it, something like /// *random comment here* \, I never thought something within a comment would even be able to cause compiling errors.

Comment: @CarlosJimenezBermudez: It's not what's in the comment that caused the error, it's what wasn't outside the comment.  Your `};` was commented out, and the compiler only looks at code outside comments.

Comment: BTW, editing `*Solved*` into the title is not the thing to do here.  Instead, write your own answer and accept it.

Comment: I checked it well and many times after I noticed in fact, it was a one line comment and the }; was in the line below. It had the usual coloring as well.

Comment: I can't write an answer to my own question until 8 hours after the question, so it will stay this way until tomorrow I guess...

Comment: Nah - please just wait until you can post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors imply that the compiler thinks those definitions are found lexically within the class definition, which implies a missing `};` or somesuch.

That's all I can say from the information provided.

Comment: After checking every single one of my 32 files I found nothing the like, which is not surprising since it did compile before me trying to refactor that specific class. Given the size of my project posting the whole code would be madness, so I really don't know what else could I provide...

Comment: @CarlosJimenezBermudez: You don't post the whole project; you reproduce the issue in a complete, minimal testcase. In doing so you'll almost certainly find the problem yourself actually, which is why it's a crucial step in the pre-internet debug phase...

Comment: I know well what a minimal and complete code sample is, but I hadn't located the specific part of the problem by then, and the two files affected were 300 lines each, that's still too much.

Comment: Try to remove BulletPlacer::   from declarations inside class.

Comment: @kyasar: Probably a bit late now...